# Alert if Duplicate entry is inserted in data base on unique condition javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

Am trying to create a alert condition if the duplicate value is inserted to DB on duplicate entry of data on unique state 
Example on my code below as test table's all columns are unique and insert query has a repeated entry of data on that i need to show sql error

Create Query

```
    var db = openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "demo", 200000);

            db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (Slno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column1 TEXT UNIQUE, column2 TEXT UNIQUE, column3 TEXT UNIQUE, column4 TEXT UNIQUE, column5 TEXT UNIQUE)");
        });
```

Insert Query

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (column1, column2 ,column3, column4,column5) VALUES ('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5'),('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5');");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a error callback function that is being called when an sql error occurs.

```
tx.executeSql(query, values, successHandler, errorHandler);
```

Note that there is room for both an error and a success function.

```
function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
    alert("Error : " + error.message);
}
```

Also use a success function like this

```
function successHandler  (transaction, resultSet) {
            if (!resultSet.rowsAffected ) {
                // Previous insert failed. Bail.
                alert('No rows affected!');
                return false;
            }else if (resultSet.rowsAffected == 1){
                 alert("ONLY one row inserted");
            }
}
```

Because your insert query does not really have an error, it executes fine but does not insert both queries.

Comment: Thank s for the reply but it is not working database is opened and a table is also created but the value are not inserted can you help he hear http://jsfiddle.net/chsgf50t/11/

Comment: Edited my answer. Check the success callback

Comment: my question was hear if i add the errorHandler as suggested next to value query that doesn't works `tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (column1, column2 ,column3, column4,column5) VALUES ('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5');",errorHandler);`

Comment: the place where i have placed the `errorHandler` is it correct i think am placing the `errorHandler` in a wrong place or ma be the placement code is wrong need a conformation on that

Comment: It is in the wrong place indeed, if you use no success you need to put null, before the errorhandler.
I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chsgf50t/12/ though I am not able to test it on my browser for some reason.

Comment: i have a quick question on duplicate data insert which is present in the DB will it show error hear am not getting the error message

Comment: Check the last part of the answer, it will probably not show an error but it will give you `affectedRows == 1` since only one row is inserted.

Comment: `tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (column1, column2 ,column3, column4,column5) VALUES ('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5');",successHandler,errorHandler);` if i add the two `successHandler,errorHandler` function then the data is not at all inserted in to db